# Exit with code 15

Tags: iphone

What does it mean when your app exits with code 15?

How can it be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely app-specific. (It is sort of a convention that an exit value of 0 means success and nonzero values mean error, but even this is not a standard.) Without knowing what app you are talking about, I doubt anyone would be able to tell you the meaning of that (supposedly) error code.

Comment: I think it might have been my device trying to sync to itunes. the app crashed, then after a few seconds it started syncing.